# Accessing Group-viewable Google Cloud Storage Buckets via API

Tags: google-cloud-storage, google-api-php-client, google-groups

I have a couple Cloud Storage buckets I want to access programatically via API, but the buckets are visible solely to members of a google group. (They're for Doubleclick bid manager reports, if that helps) I provided the name and group email address for a group that I made specifically to get access to these cloud storage buckets.

Looking around on my individual developer console, I can gain access to authentication stuff so I can access my own google account's buckets, but when I use the credentials from my google developer console's project, hopefully granting me access based on which account I'm using (Which I'm assuming is totally wrong) using this code:

```
    $key = file_get_contents("[PATH_TO_KEY].p12");
    $cred = new Google_Auth_AssertionCredentials("[ACCOUNT STUFF]", 
                                                array("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/devstorage.full_control"), 
                                                $key);
    $client->setAssertionCredentials($cred);
    $client->setClientId($client_id);
    $client->setClientSecret($client_secret);
    $client->setDeveloperKey($dev_api_key);
    $client->setRedirectUri($redirect);
    $client->setScopes("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/devstorage.full_control");
    $service = new Google_Service_Storage($client);
    $bucket = $service->objects->listObjects($da_bucket);
```

I get a 403. (I might also be authenticating wrong. sorry trying to POC something here)

Is there some place where I can gain API access for a bucket that's accessible for all members of a Google group, but not specifically me?

Answer (score 2):

The service account associated with that .p12 key needs to be a member of the group that can read the bucket.

Comment: But aren't the .p12 keys associated with the single API project? I've made one under my google account, the same one that created the google group that has access to the bucket.

Comment: Nope. A .p12 key is associated with a single service account. That account is a member of its project but doesn't share the same permissions as your own account.

Comment: Buh, looking at how the groups permissions interact between users in my group, it looks like the permissions don't even care about groups. I just straight up don't know how to authenticate properly, seeing as I can use https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/json_api/v1/objects/list test function just fine. Thanks for the help anyway.

Comment: Er, the permissions issue that I'm actually having, that is. Duh.